# Criar um próprio escopo a cada iteração do ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela de valores a serem preenchidos e armazenados, linha a linha. Porém, mesmo após preenchida e armazenada a primeira linha, ao alterar o valor de um select, o select de todas as linhas acima da que eu estou inserindo estão tendo seus valores alterados.

É possível isolar cada linha com um escopo próprio?

Código:

```
 <tr class="odd" ng-repeat="itemSaida in vm.itensSaida"> 
                                <!-- SELECT DE PRODUTOS -->
                                <td class="expand">
                                     <span class="responsiveExpander">
                                         <select class="form-control" ng-disabled="itemSaida.id && !itemSaida.editando" ng-model="itemSaida.fkProduto" ng-options="produto.id as (produto.id + '-' + produto.nome) for produto in vm.produtos" ng-change="post('carregar-estoque/'+ itemSaida.fkProduto, {indice: $index})">
                                             <option value="">-- SELECIONE --</option>
                                         </select>
                                     </span>
                                </td>

                                <!-- Unidade -->
                                <td class="expand">
                                     <span class="responsiveExpander">
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" ng-disabled="true" auto-focus ng-model="vm.unidade">
                                     </span>
                                </td>

                               <!-- SELECT DE ESTOQUES -->
                               <td class="expand">
                                   <span class="responsiveExpander">
                                        <select class="form-control" ng-disabled="itemSaida.id && !itemSaida.editando" ng-model="itemSaida.fkEstoque" ng-options="fkEstoque.id as (fkEstoque.tipoEstoque.nome + ': Qtde:' + fkEstoque.quantidade) for fkEstoque in vm.estoques" ng-change="get('carregar-data-vencimento/'+itemSaida.fkEstoque)">
                                            <option value="">-- SELECIONE --</option>
                                        </select>
                                   </span>
                               </td>

                               <!-- Vencimento -->
                               <td class="expand">
                                    <span class="responsiveExpander">
                                        <input ng-model="vm.vencimento" mask="date" type="text" class="form-control text-left" ng-disabled="true" auto-focus>
                                    </span>
                               </td>

                               <td class="expand">
                                    <span class="responsiveExpander">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" ng-disabled="itemSaida.id && !itemSaida.editando" ng-model="itemSaida.quantidade" id="quantidade" mask="decimal" maxlength="15" placeholder="Quantidade">
                                    </span>
                               </td>
```

Para ficar um pouco mais simples de entender: trata-se de um cadastro de itens em que cada linha de uma tabela será responsável por cadastrar um item. A figura abaixo ilustra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após salvar o primeiro item, quando eu vou selecionar o produto na linha de baixo, está atualizando a unidade tanto na linha de cima quanto na de baixo, mas a de cima deveria ficar com o valor antigo. Isso está acontecendo por causa do angular. É feita uma requisição get no servidor, que atualiza a variável vm.unidade, que acaba atualizando ambas as linhas..

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta, tem como postar o código? ou mostrar um print

Comment: Testei isso que você postou e não ocorre no meu teste. Talvez precisamos de mais código seu para podermos descobrir o por que desse comportamento.

Comment: Gente, obrigado pelo feedback. Postei uma imagem sobre o problema e uma melhor descrição. Veja se vocês conseguem me ajudar por favor.